# How to add empty lines at the beginning of a code sample?

Tags: support, markdown

What is the official way to add empty lines at the beginning of a code block?

```
 
2nd line
```

I had to use this feature [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39573742/whitespace-control-in-shopify-liquid) today.

Comment: i do have to ask *why* you need an empty line at the start of the code block? why can't you just omit it? it's not like the code posted will be broken if it wasn't there

Comment: I had to use it **[in this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39573742/whitespace-control-in-shopify-liquid)** today

Comment: i see. though in that situation since output/render is being quoted i would use `> <br/>hello`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `<pre></pre>`:

```
It lets you add an empty line below too!
```

Source:

```
<pre>

It lets you add an empty line below too!

</pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

The workaround I've found is to add the invisible space character by pressing <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd> (on Mac OS X)

Comment: Hm, I wouldn't really go for this option for the exact reason that its invisible; it looks like a mistake that people may want to edit out. Using visible tags to get your formatting done reads a whole lot more like its working as intended.